# follow a body in html5 canvas and box2d

Tags: javascript, box2d, html5-canvas

Am using the physics engine box2dweb , my problam is that I have a body and I want to follow him , example my canvas width:500px height:500px and the body  coordination is (700,200) so I cant see him  so how to make him visible in my canvas

Answer (score 0):

You should use the debug drawing of box2dweb.

```
function debugDraw(){
    var debugDraw = new b2DebugDraw();
//replace canvas with your canvas id
    debugDraw.SetSprite(document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d"));
    debugDraw.SetDrawScale(30.0);
    debugDraw.SetFillAlpha(0.5);
    debugDraw.SetLineThickness(1.0);
    debugDraw.SetFlags(b2DebugDraw.e_shapeBit | b2DebugDraw.e_jointBit);
    world.SetDebugDraw(debugDraw); // replace world with your box2dworld
}
```

Put this function in your gameloop.